# Why Halliday and Resnick book does not follow ASTM E29 rounding rules?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

They warn this in the beginning of first chapter, but my question is why. Is there a special reason for that, since we know that can introduce bias in data?

For instance, in the chapter 2, first problem, they ask the displacement of a 90 km/h car while you sneeze with eyes shut for 0.5 seconds.

$\frac{1 \;\mathrm{m/s}}{3.6\;\mathrm{km/h}}\times 90\;\mathrm{km/h}\times 0.5\;\mathrm{s} = 12.5\;\mathrm{m}$.

As ASTM E29 states, this rounds to 12, since 2 is even. However, in the back of the book, the answer is 13.

As I said, they warn this in the beginning, but why?

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: Well, why not? Ok, it is just a textbook question, but since ASTM E29 are taught in lab classes, I think that textbooks calculations also should follow the rules.

Comment: Do physicists follow rules? Have you read "Surely you're joking, Mr. Feynman!"? ツ

Comment: There are many rounding rules (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) - why is E29 preferred over any of the other methods? When was E29 formalized, and when was H&R written?

Comment: John Doty, it is a good point (lol). Yes, I read this one and this closes the question :D

Comment: Jon Custer, yes, I'm aware of that. But most rules I know uses the round 5-even scheme. Otherwise I will introduce bias in lab data, right? Because 50% of time we round up and 50% round down, don't we?

Comment: In other words, my question could be: "why the most famous physics textbook does not follow round 5 even?" It is a convention in the book, but this is not much matter of convention, since it is statistically explainable, far as I know.

Comment: Just because ASTM E29 rules are taught in *some* lab classes doesn't mean that they're universal.

Comment: Michael, maybe my question sound silly and I was wrong in focus at ASTM. I'm not that stupid. But the sense of my question remains if we replace ASTM E29 for round 5-even rule.